# How to apply active-class prop in Vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, less

Below was the old question, I realize the issue is not with the custom properties, but rather I have a component like the below, and 'active-class' is not being applied.

I tried to change the prop name to `activeClass`, doesn't seem to be working

```
<VListGroup
                  key={item.text}
                  class='drawer-item'
                  active-class='drawer-active-item'
                >
```

I'm working on a new project using Vue, and trying to convert some old components (.vue) files to be using render functions and typescript (.tsx), and trying to separate the style contained in the `<style/>` blocks into a separate `.less` file.

While the template syntax, v-if and all can be converted quite easily, however I'm stuck on the part where if my style contains `customProperties`, [https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-properties]]](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-properties%5D%5D)

specifically `--v-primary-base`, as the below

I have the below

```
  .drawer-active-item {
    color: white;
    &::before {
      background-color: var(--v-primary-base);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    &::after {
      background-color: var(--v-primary-base);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    &:hover::after {
      background-color: var(--v-primary-base);
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to access these custom css variables from the `.less` file? I've been googling things like 'access customProperties in less file` and things related, but I feel like perhaps I'm not asking the right question, or looking at the right resource for what I'm trying to achieve, pointers would be great, thank you.

I have a theme config that currently looks like the below, just for some context.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md',
  },
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.blue.darken3,
      },
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blue.darken3,
        anchor: colors.blue.base,
      },
    },
  },
});
```